# How to remove first three characters from string with C?

Tags: c, string

How would I remove the first three letters of a string with C?

Comment: "plz send teh codez!!1" - "No."

Comment: `str = str + 3;` since `str+=3;` is too short for a comment!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
void chopN(char *str, size_t n)
{
    assert(n != 0 && str != 0);
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len)
        return;  // Or: n = len;
    memmove(str, str+n, len - n + 1);
}
```

An alternative design:

```
size_t chopN(char *str, size_t n)
{
    assert(n != 0 && str != 0);
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len)
        n = len;
    memmove(str, str+n, len - n + 1);
    return(len - n);
}
```

Comment: +1, but wouldn't it be better as int, which prints the # of chars actually remaining (or -1 instead of the assertion) ?

Comment: @Tim: there are all sorts of possible designs; this is a roughly minimal implementation - on the whole, I think the assignment is better than the early return.  As to the return value - I'd be fine with returning the reduced length - that would be `size_t` like the input, most likely.

Answer (score 36):

Add 3 to the pointer:

```
char *foo = "abcdef";
foo += 3;
printf("%s", foo);
```

will print "def"

Comment: Need to check to make sure it's at least three characters long first!

Answer (score 11):

For example, if you have

```
char a[] = "123456";
```

the simplest way to remove the first 3 characters will be:

```
char *b = a + 3;  // the same as to write `char *b = &a[3]`
```

b will contain "456"

But in general case you should also make sure that string length not exceeded

Comment: Not only is `sizeof(char)` **useless**, it's also **wrong** for other types. Pointer arithmetic takes place in units of elements, not bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In C, string is an array of characters in continuous locations. We can't either increase or decrease the size of the array. But make a new char array of size of original size minus 3 and copy characters into new array.

Comment: That'll copy the first three characters of the string. The question asks how to *remove* the first three characters.

Comment: Yeah Just noticed.Changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, learn about string copy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcpy), indexing into a string (http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) and try again.  In pseudocode:

```
find the pointer into the string where you want to start copying from
copy from that point to end of string into a new string.
```

Comment: -1. Code without explanation is better than links to references and completely obvious "pseudocode".