# Remove first few characters from a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, memmove

I need to remove the first 3 characters from an *array* without any libraries. How would I go about doing this? I know that I can use `memmove` but I'm working on a system without the standard library, also `memmove` is for pointers. With `memmove` I can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761764/how-to-remove-first-three-characters-from-string-with-c):

```
void chopN(char *str, size_t n)
{
    assert(n != 0 && str != 0);
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len)
        return;  // Or: n = len;
    memmove(str, str+n, len - n + 1);
}
```

But could I remove characters from an array without `memmove` or any other standard library functions?

Comment: does "remove" mean you also want to free the memory? if not (and it's only about output), you''d simply have your pointer point to the new start, i.e. str += 3

Comment: @Ur Mom Are you allowed to use strlen?

Comment: Note: see no need for `n != 0` in `assert(n != 0 && str != 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know the string is at least 3 characters long, you can simply use `str + 3`.

Comment: Potentially dangerous if you don't save the original pointer and need to `free` it later.  Doesn't matter if it is on the stack though.

Comment: @Cody Sure, you could come up with 1000 ways to hurt yourself in C. Strictly speaking this is the best way to accomplish what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm: 2 simple while loops should do it.

Some untested code to give you an idea.

```
void chopN(char *str, size_t n) {
  char *dest = str;

  // find beginning watching out for rump `str`
  while (*str && n--) {
    str++;
  }

  // Copy byte by byte
  while (*src) {
    *dest++ = *src++;
  }

  *dest = '\0';
}
```

Could add a `if (n==0)` short-cut if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that does not use standard C string functions. `n` can be less then or equal to `strlen( s )`. Otherwise the function does nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * chopN( char *s, size_t n )
{
    char *src = s;

    while ( *src && n ) --n, ++src;

    if ( n == 0 && src != s )
    {
        for ( char *dst = s; (  *dst++ = *src++ ); );
    }

    return s;
}   

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello, World";

    puts( s );
    puts( chopN( s, 7 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello, World
World
```

If you want that in case when `n` is greater than `strlen( s )` all characters were removed then it is enough to substituted the if statement

```
if ( n == 0 && src != s )
```

for this one

```
if ( src != s )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the "amount" of characters as a parameter, you can search for '\0':

```
void chopN(char *str, size_t n){
    char *aux;
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if(i>n+1){
            aux[j++]=str[i++];
        }else i++;
    }
    aux[j]='\0';
    str = aux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply start at the new start (str+n) and copy to the old start char by char until you reach the end of the string:

```
char *str1;
for(str1 = str+n; *str1; *str++=*str1++) 
   ;
*str = 0;
```

If you want something more powerful, you can e.g., steal a memmove implementation from http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/memmove.c (it basically does the same thing, except with some performance tweaks and a decision on which way (left/right) the move goes).